# Using an Outline with XPages Extension Library Mobile Controls

Tags: xpages, mobile-controls, xpages-extlib

I am using the XPages Extension Library mobile controls to create a mobile web interface for an existing Notes app.

When displaying a document with a large number of fields I would like to use an accordion type UI so that parts of the page can be expanded or collapsed to show or hide the fields in each pane (similar to sections in a traditional Notes client app).

Having looked at the "Accordion Outline" in the Ext Lib demo app I started to build the page using the Outline control. Within each entry (node) of the Outline I, ideally, want to place a rounded list and then put my fields & controls inside that.

But it looks like the nodes in the Outline can't contain this type of content - unless I'm missing something?

Any suggestions as to which controls I can use this type of UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can any time use an xp:panel and assign it the dijit.accordeon (look up the exact name please) dojo type. Then you can put anything inside including repeat controls etc. I would guess it might make sense to build your own CC to hold the content for each accordeon panel